# Capturing annotated parameter with aspect in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, aspectj

with aspect, I am trying to capture annotated parameters, but it is not working.

Annotation is as follows:

```java
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface DTO {}
```

The service class where I have annotated the parameters in a few methods are as follows:

```java
@Service
class MyService {
  public MyDTO update(@DTO MyDTO myDTO) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Now with the help of aspect, I am trying to capture those annotated parameters as follows:

```java
@Aspect
class MyAspect {
  // ...

  @Before(value = "applicationServicePointcut()", argNames = "joinPoint")
  public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, StateManagement stateManagement)
    throws Throwable {
      // ...
      // HERE I AM ALWAYS GETTING NULL
      Object object = getAnnotatedParameter(joinPoint, DTO.class);
      // ...
  } 

  public Object getAnnotatedParameter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Class<?> annotatedClazz) {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Parameter[] params = methodSignature.getMethod().getParameters();
    for (Parameter param : params) {
      if (isParamAnnotatedWith(param, annotatedClazz.getName())) 
      {
        return param;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private boolean isParamAnnotatedWith(Parameter param, String annotationClassName) {
    for (Annotation annotation : param.getAnnotations()) {
      System.out.println("Annotation class name : " + annotation.getClass().getName());
      // HERE IN annotation.getClass().getName() I am getting com.sun.proxy.$Proxy375
      if (annotation.getClass().getName().equals(annotationClassName)) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I am clueless regarding how to capture the annotated parameter with aspect. Could anyone please help here? Thanks.

Comment: Please learn how to ask good questions and read what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is. Nobody can debug `...`. For example, why would you post an aspect but intentionally omit the pointcut? If you fix your code to be an MCVE, I promise I am going to answer your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if I were you I would pass on the annotation type as `Class<?>` from `getAnnotatedParameter` to `isParamAnnotatedWith` in order to make processing easier.

The actual bug in your code is that you use `getClass()` on an annotation instance, which always yields a JDK dynamic proxy class, because this is what it is internally in Java. Instead, you ought to use method `annotationType()`, which gives you exactly what you need.

```java
public Object getAnnotatedParameter(JoinPoint joinPoint, Class<?> annotationType) {
  Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
  for (Parameter parameter : method.getParameters()) {
    if (isParamAnnotatedWith(parameter, annotationType))
      return parameter;
  }
  return null;
}

private boolean isParamAnnotatedWith(Parameter parameter, Class<?> annotationType) {
  for (Annotation annotation : parameter.getAnnotations()) {
    if (annotation.annotationType().equals(annotationType))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```